# Button to copy text but remove formatting

Tags: javascript

I know very little about javascript, but I'm sure there's a way to do this. I have a website containing a few paragraphs of text inside a  I would like to add a button that will copy all of the text inside a div, so I can paste it on social media. The issue I'm having is that it copies all of the website markup too, like the `<p>` and `<strong>` tags and whatnot. How can I JUST copy the text without the markup, but also preserve the line breaks for the different paragraphs.

Comment: You might use `.textContent` or `.innerText`, can you give an example of the input and desired output?

Comment: Please consider to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if possible. This way, it's more likely volunteers on SO can help you.

Comment: TextContent worked, thanks! Sorry... I'm new here, next time I'll try to post sample code, etc...